# Solidity compiler command-line utility (solcjs) various problems

Tags: solc, compilation, command-line

I am trying to compile a file using `solcjs` from a command-line, and running into various problems.

First of all, I need to supply in the command-line all the files that are imported by the primary file.

Otherwise I get `ParserError: Source "SomeFile.sol" not found: File not supplied initially`.

But when I do supply these files, I get a bunch of other problems.

The main issue seems to be the fact the one of the imported files resides in a sub-folder.

First I noticed that I cannot use a backslash, i.e., can only use a slash (I should emphasize that I am running on Windows).

So I've fixed that.

Then I noticed that I cannot use a relative path, i.e., must use the full path of the file.

So I've fixed that too.

I was able to detect and solve these problems by attempting to compile that specific file **by itself**.

Now back to my original goal - once I specify this file in the list of files passed to `solcjs`, I keep getting that `File not supplied initially` error.

Here is the command line that I am using:

```
solcjs --optimize --bin --abi -o build C:/project/util/file1.sol file2.sol main.sol
```

When I compile each one of the imported files separately, I get `abi` and `bin` files inside the `build` output directory:

```
solcjs --optimize --bin --abi -o build C:/project/util/file1.sol
solcjs --optimize --bin --abi -o build file2.sol
```

But no matter what I do, I am unable to compile the main file.

Compiler version is `0.4.15+commit.bbb8e64f.Emscripten.clang`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not trying to compile files on the terminal only and can use javascript to do that then this [script](https://gist.github.com/inovizz/1fdc2af0182584b90008e0cf2895554c) might help you which I wrote sometime back. I also had multiple dependent contract files which were required to compile the main contract. So I solved using following way -

Define all dependent contracts in an input object keeping the same import order and then use that object to compile your contract.

```
var input = {
    'strings.sol': fs.readFileSync('strings.sol', 'utf8'),
    'StringLib.sol': fs.readFileSync('StringLib.sol', 'utf8'),
    'Killable.sol': fs.readFileSync('Killable.sol', 'utf8'),
    'Ownable.sol': fs.readFileSync('Ownable.sol', 'utf8'),
    'LMS.sol': fs.readFileSync('LMS.sol', 'utf8')
};
let compiledContract = solc.compile({sources: input}, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Note: This requires basic nodejs knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this answer elsewhere in here. But how exactly should I execute this script? Thank you.

Comment: With the help of NodeJs, install nodejs on your machine and then run 
"node script.js"

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`.

Comment: run "npm install fs"

Comment: it worked?, if then let me know I'll help you out in through chat option.

Comment: Did you mean "npm install fs -g"? Anyways, I still get the same error.

Comment: OK, added `const fs = require("fs");` from your linked script, which solves this problem (BTW, not quite sure why you posted that link, and then the partial code snippet immediately following it). Anyways, the problem now is `Cannot find module 'solc'`. And yes - I have called `npm install solc -g`.